# Please explain the following auto layout behavior to me

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios8

I'm currently trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with the following constraint-based UITableViewCell layout (iOS 8).

My cell is laid out as shown in this image:

[image]

There is an image view on the left, a label on the right, and both should be touching the cell margins everywhere. The image has a fixed size (64x64), the label's height will always be smaller than that. I want the image's height to cause the cell to expand the height to the correct value (image height + 2 * margin).

The problem is this: I have three constraints for the vertical size, `V[Image(64)]`, `Reset.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView.bottomMargin` and `Reset.top == UITableViewCellContentView.topMargin` (all defined via the storyboard). When I display the cell, I get an unsatisfiable constraints error. The `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` constraint interferes with my constraints, and auto layout breaks my image view height constraint. Everything looks as it should, but I don't like errors at runtime.

If I give my height constraint the priority 999, everything looks fine, no errors.

So my understanding is, that my height constraint will be broken in both cases at runtime.

But when I delete the height constraint altogether, the image displays at its original height (the file has different resolution than what I display in the cell). Why is this, or what am I getting wrong here?

**Edit/Update**: I just noticed I was wrong about everything working. The initial display of my cell is fine, but when the cell changes (in my case I am moving another, simple single line label, cell below it) my cell changes its height to the default row height (44 pts), squashing the image in the process. This happens in both cases, when auto layout breaks my constraints or when I reduce the priority of height to 999. I'm really at a loss as to how to get these cells to do what I want.

Comment: Did they do something new in iOS 8 and you can now resize table view cell from the cell itself?

Comment: Yeah, there's something about dynamic cell heights. It's part of the autolayout-for-everything plan I think. Basically, `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath` should not be needed anymore.

Comment: If so, it needs to be like several times faster than in iOS 7. I used autolayout in cells (even when `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath` return the same value) and it was reeeeaaaaally slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the `estimatedRowHeight` property in code, and also, depending on which version of iOS 6 you're using, set the `rowHeight` property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`,

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

The default rowHeight for nib or storyboard table views, is supposed to be changed to UITableViewAutomaticDimension at some point; I don't know if it has yet in 6.0.1, so that last line may or may not be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned that I've tried both of those lines (in viewDidLoad), to no avail. Also, I'm using Xcode 6.1 Beta if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supporting older version of iOS? If that is the case, be sure to uncheck the `Relative to margin` option for the constraints that are complaining.

[image]

Comment: I decided that learning the new way to do something and at the same time maintaining backwards compatibility to something I only have half-knowledge of was too much for me, so I'm only supporting iOS 8. All constraints where one item belongs to the superview are relative to margin.